# test.runsettings overwrites log file with every execution

Tags: c#, logging, mstest

I would like the log files to be generated in the following format:
results_[timestamp string].xml
Currently I'm executing SQL unit tests tests from Visual Studio. They were created using MSTest.

My run.settings file

```
<RunSettings>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger friendlyName="trx" enabled=True>
      <Configuration> 
        <LogFileName>r.trx</LogFileName>
      </Configuration>
    </Logger>
  </Loggers>
</RunSettings>
```